# Does the expression 'a person without a core' make sense?

Tags: word-request

The context where I want to use this expression is as follows:

> The stronger the urge to make yourself known, the more likely you are to end up papering an entire wall of your cubicle with all sorts of images. In the end, this not only diminishes the impact of your message, but also leaves an impression of you being *a person without(lacking) a core*.

> The stronger the urge to make yourself known, the more likely you are to end up papering an entire wall of your cubicle with all sorts of images. In the end, this not only diminishes the impact of your message, but also leaves an impression of you being *a person without a center*.

Any other way to express this?

Comment: What are you trying to say? Without knowing that, it is not possible to say what other way to express that you could use.

Comment: Your sentences are vague. What is a ‘person without a core’? How can a person have/not have a center?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check some definitions or terms related to the words in question.
For example, if you check the definition of [core](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/core) there is an adjective usage:

> (12.) central, basic, or most important; main ⇒ "core values, core knowledge"

*core* by itself is not meaningful in your context, but *core values* probably would.

> ...but also leaves an impression of you being a person without(lacking) **core values**.

In the second example, I don't think you can use *center* by itself, because you cannot tell the center of what. But there is a phrase *moral center* that might make sense.

> ...but also leaves an impression of you being a person **without a moral center**.

Regarding the full example, more context is needed to understand whether these terms actually describe the scenario. As it is, it just sounds like a cluttered cubicle.